# Delete cells with a specific value

Tags: vba

I am trying to do something simple. From column N in Log Frame info copy only unique values starting at B62 of Dropdown - this part works! Then, if one of the values in B62:B80 is "other" delete that cell - this part works sometimes and not others, can't tell why. Help!

```
Sub test()


Dim RngDest As Range
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range

Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("b61:b80").ClearContents

Set Rng = Sheets("Log Frame Info").Range("N4:N500")
Set RngDest = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("B62")

Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=RngDest, Unique:=True

With Sheets("Dropdowns")
    Set Rng = Range("B61:b80")
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell = "Other" Then
            Cell.Delete
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because once a cell has been deleted, the `For` loop is continuing to the next cell rather than evaluating the new value of the cell. Something like this should work as it counts when a cell has been deleted and offsets the `If` call:

```
Sub test()

Dim RngDest As Range
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("b61:b80").ClearContents

Set Rng = Sheets("Log Frame Info").Range("N4:N500")
Set RngDest = Sheets("Dropdowns").Range("B62")

Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=RngDest, Unique:=True

With Sheets("Dropdowns")
    Set Rng = Range("B61:b80")
    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell.Offset(-i, 0) = "Other" Then
            Cell.Delete
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: May I add never understimate the power of `Step -1`. If you can count your cells, you may be willing to delete them starting from the last one, so when the counter decreases (with -1 step) your "next" cell is actually there.